How can I convert a nb::handle (or nb::object or PyObject*) into a nb::ndarray?
Nanobind has a function nb::ndarray_check(handle h) which returns true in case h is usable as an ndarray (e.g. if it implements the buffer protocol).
How do I actually create an instance of nb::ndarray from h?
nb::ndarray has a constructor explicit ndarray(detail::ndarray_handle *handle). But there seems to be none which takes a simple PyObject*, nb::handle, or nb::object as an argument.

The "buffer protocol" means you can call PyObject_GetBuffer to get a description of the backing store. Most of these parameters map one-to-one to the ndarray constructur arguments. For the DLPack protocol you are supposed to call the __dlpack__ method, which returns a DLPack capsule with a dltensor field

It looks like this is what nb::ndarray::detail::type_caster does for you but I have no idea how to tie this to the general cast infrastructure
